# Moment js subtract 2 times

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hello everybody i want to subtract 2 times from each other like i have time in this second in variable called _start

 `_start :any=moment().format('LTS'); // 4:01:15`

and i have the time after 5 seconds in variable called _end

```
 _end = moment().format('LTS'); // 4:01:20
```

then i want the difference between them which is 0:00:05
how can i do that in moment.js i already used 
`_end.diff(_start, "seconds")`
i got an error says that _end.diff is not a function.thank u
if u don't understand me please check toggl.com i want to make a task like this website.

Answer (score 2):

You should format the final date. Otherwise you'll need to reparse.

```
 _start = moment();
 //later
 _end = moment();

 moment(_end.diff(_start)).format('H:mm:ss'); // 4:01:15
 moment(_end.diff(_start)).format('H:mm:ss A'); // 4:01:15 PM
```

Comment: Ok thank u it worked for me but is there is another way to make the output looks like this if the result is one second  ==> 0:00:01 or one minute ==> 
0:01:00 or one hour ==> 1:00:00 @Jemiloll

Comment: i updated the question, all you need to do is add `.format('LTS')` to the moment chain.

Comment: @Jemiloll thank u for ur reply but i have an error said Property 'format' does not exist on type 'string'  this is my code  
`
  bs:any;
  bbs:any;
  tasks:timeInterface[] =[];

  startPause() {
    this.bs = moment();
    this.startTime = moment().format('LT');
}
showdiv() {
    this.bbs = moment();
    let x:number =moment(this.bbs).diff(moment(this.bs), "seconds").format('LTS');
    console.log(x);
    this.show = true;
    this.stopTime = moment().format('LT');
    if(!this.pause) {
      this.startTime = this.stopTime
    }
  }
`

Comment: apparently moment won't do this anymore `var LT = moment().format('LT'); moment(LT).format('LTS');` they are depreciating it since it's not an ISO standard. So keep it to `_start = moment();` and `_end = moment();` you can always do `_start.format('LTS')` later. this way your moment.diff is cleaner.

Comment: i gave it an update, should be what your looking for. avoid doing any formatting until you need it. Also LTS is a bit picky, so i switched to state what fields you want.

Comment: @Jemiloll whay when i subtract the start which is for ex: 4:01:15 from end which is 4:01:20 using
    moment(end.diff(start).format('LTS')) it gives me 2:00:05 instead 00:00:05

Comment: `moment(end.diff(start)).format('LTS')` you need to format afterwards. plus try an avoid using LTS for what your trying to acomplish. it does not work with diff correctly. LTS requires a full timestamp. `.format('H:mm:ss');` H - hour without prefix 0, mm - minutes with prefix 0, ss - seconds with prefix 0